# Redshift regex_replace to select specific comma separated string pattern

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

Using redshift and trying to parse patterns to extract User ID(Bold character) out from comma separated contact number.

Input Data-

| `column_identifier` |
| --- |
| **`4e1d3332-2523-41a1-a155-17611197042b`**`,+919999999999` |
| `+911234567890,`**`1e1e3b02-2553-51c1-a455-1761f197042b`** |
| **`6e1d3w02-2553-41c1-a455-1232w197042b`**`,+919999999888,+919999999988` |

Query in redshift is as below:

`select regexp_substr(column_identifier, '(\w*[-]\w*[-]\w*[-]\w*[-]\w*)')`

expected_output

| `Column A` |
| --- |
| **`4e1d3332-2523-41a1-a155-17611197042b`** |
| **`1e1e3b02-2553-51c1-a455-1761f197042b`** |
| **`6e1d3w02-2553-41c1-a455-1232w197042b`** |

Tried multiple regex patterns, Any of you kindly guide me in here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this page [REGEXP_SUBSTR function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) supporting the syntax on the page about [POSIX operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html) and the examples show to double escape the `\\w`

Note that you don't need the outer capture group for a match only, and in your example `\w*` would match 0 or more repetitions.

You could write the pattern as with a capture group that is repeated 4 times:

```
\\w+(-\\w+){4}
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/02CGfZ/1).

Or you might also make the match a bit more specific

```
[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+){4}
```